# TWRP: No OS flashed after flashing LOS 16.0 on Samsung S5

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, lineageos, side-loading

I want to install LOS 16.0 on my Samsung S5 SM-G901F. According to the [LOS installation wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/kccat6/install), I did from an ArchLinux OS:

- installation of [TWRP 3.2.3-0](https://dl.twrp.me/kccat6/twrp-3.2.3-0-kccat6.img.html) with heimdall
- wipe -> format data
- wipe -> advanced wipe (all partitions were wiped)
- advanced ADB sideload: adb sideload lineage-16.0-20200106-nightly-kccat6-signed.zip (I tried the 3 [last build](https://download.lineageos.org/kccat6))

I checked all the hashes and they are Ok.

I observed a progress-bar difference between the TWRP and the terminal: the TWRP announced a 100% progress, while the adb command stopped at 47%. However, after debugging it, I realized the installation script runs entirely.

Finally, when I wish to reboot on the system partition, I get the error message "No OS flashed are you sure you wish to reboot?".

Have you any idea to truly flash LOS?
Thank you!

Comment: wiping ALL partitions is a very bad idea, especially for unofficial TWRP builds where critical partitions like nvdata, nvram, aboot, ... left in fstab. for LineageOS wipe System only

Answer (score 1):

if you wiped all partitions under TWRP advanced wipe. You need to flash Samsung factory firmware because you wiped the framework that the ROM is built over.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I was able to install LOS